# How to remove application from IIS7 website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We are migrating some ASP.NET applications from IIS6 to 7. In IIS6, you could create a website and then REMOVE the application. We have several sites with static content to migrate so we would like to do the same in IIS7 but cannot seem to find a way to remove the application.

OTOH is there any overhead to having a website in IIS7 that has an application but nothing ever compiles or 'executes'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the non-executable applications are now called Virtual Directories. Map the "applications" as that.

Comment: Thanks - but when you create a WEBSITE (not app) you pick an app pool, etc. For even a site that simply redirects it still 'seems' to have an application associated with it?